# php loop through an array looking for all fields that contain 1

Tags: php

I have a query that looks up a record which works fine. I then need to echo all the fields name that start with "Seq" and contain "1".

my query:

```
SELECT * FROM ROSE_Hist
WHERE UniqueID = '1919' AND  1 IN ( SeqID0101,SeqID0102,SeqID0103 ,SeqID0104,SeqID0105,SeqID0106,SeqID0107,SeqID0108,SeqID0109,SeqID0110,SeqID0201,SeqID0202,SeqID0203,SeqID0301,SeqID0302,SeqID0303,SeqID0304,SeqID0401,SeqID0402,SeqID0403,SeqID0404,SeqID0501,
SeqID0502,SeqID0601,SeqID0602,SeqID0701,SeqID0702,SeqID0801,SeqID0802,SeqID0901,SeqID0902,SeqID0903,SeqID1001,SeqID1002,SeqID1003,SeqID1004,SeqID1101,SeqID1102,SeqID1201,SeqID1302,SeqID1303,SeqID1304,SeqID1305,
SeqID1401,SeqID1402,SeqID1403,SeqID1404,SeqID1405,SeqID1406,SeqID1407,SeqID1408,SeqID1409,SeqID1410,SeqID1411,SeqID1501,SeqID1502,SeqID1504,SeqID1505,SeqID1601,SeqID1602,SeqID1603,SeqID1604,SeqID1605,SeqID1701,SeqID1702,SeqID1703,SeqID1704,
SeqID1705,SeqID1801,SeqID1802,SeqID1901,SeqID1902,SeqID2001,SeqID2002,SeqID2101,SeqID2102,SeqID2201,SeqID2202,SeqID2203,SeqID2301,SeqID2302,SeqID2401,SeqID2402,SeqID2403,SeqID2501,SeqID2502,SeqID2503,SeqID2601,SeqID2602,SeqID2603,SeqID2701,
SeqID2702,SeqID2703,SeqID2704,SeqID2801,SeqID2901,SeqID2902,SeqID3001,SeqID3002,SeqID3101,SeqID3201,SeqID3202,SeqID3203,SeqID3204,SeqID3301,SeqID3302,SeqID3401,SeqID3402,SeqID3501,SeqID3502,SeqID3601,SeqID3602,SeqID3603,SeqID3604,SeqID3605,
SeqID3606,SeqID3701,SeqID3702,SeqID3703,SeqID3704,SeqID3801,SeqID3802,SeqID3803,SeqID3804,SeqID3901,SeqID3902,SeqID3903,SeqID3904,SeqID4001,SeqID4002,SeqID4003,SeqID4101,SeqID4102,SeqID4201,SeqID4202,SeqID4301,SeqID4302,SeqID4303,SeqID4304,
SeqID4401,SeqID4501,SeqID4502,SeqID4503,SeqID4504,SeqID4505,SeqID4506,SeqID4507,SeqID4508,SeqID4509,SeqID4510,SeqID4511,SeqID4512,SeqID4513,SeqID4514,SeqID4601,SeqID4602,SeqID4603,SeqID4604,SeqID4701,SeqID4702,SeqID4703,SeqID4704,SeqID4705) ORDER BY Room ASC
```

Then I need to loop through the result and ech only the fields that start with "Seq" and contain the number "1".

```
foreach ($row_RoomAudit as $key => $val) {
   print "$key = $val\n";
}
```

I have something wrong here because the "foreeach" is echoing all the fields. What would I need to do just to echo the fields names that start with the name "Seq" that contain "1".

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: did you try to use string functions like strpos?

Comment: You can use `preg_match` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick workaround with [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find "1" and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to find 'Seq'

```
foreach ($row_RoomAudit as $key => $val) {
       if (strpos($val, '1') !== FALSE && substr( $val, 0, 3)=='Seq' ){
          print "$key = $val\n";
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, if (strpos($val, '1') !== FALSE && substr( $val, 0, 3)=='Seq' ){ Should be if (strpos($val, '1') !== FALSE && substr( $key 0, 3)=='Seq' ){, that works.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are SELECTING all fields using `*`. If you only want to select those specific columns, you'll have to change your query to do so:

```
SELECT SeqID0101,SeqID0102,SeqID0103 ,SeqID0104,SeqID0105,SeqID0106,SeqID0107,SeqID0108,SeqID0109,SeqID0110,SeqID0201,SeqID0202,SeqID0203,SeqID0301,SeqID0302,SeqID0303,SeqID0304,SeqID0401,SeqID0402,SeqID0403,SeqID0404,SeqID0501,
SeqID0502,SeqID0601,SeqID0602,SeqID0701,SeqID0702,SeqID0801,SeqID0802,SeqID0901,SeqID0902,SeqID0903,SeqID1001,SeqID1002,SeqID1003,SeqID1004,SeqID1101,SeqID1102,SeqID1201,SeqID1302,SeqID1303,SeqID1304,SeqID1305,
SeqID1401,SeqID1402,SeqID1403,SeqID1404,SeqID1405,SeqID1406,SeqID1407,SeqID1408,SeqID1409,SeqID1410,SeqID1411,SeqID1501,SeqID1502,SeqID1504,SeqID1505,SeqID1601,SeqID1602,SeqID1603,SeqID1604,SeqID1605,SeqID1701,SeqID1702,SeqID1703,SeqID1704,
SeqID1705,SeqID1801,SeqID1802,SeqID1901,SeqID1902,SeqID2001,SeqID2002,SeqID2101,SeqID2102,SeqID2201,SeqID2202,SeqID2203,SeqID2301,SeqID2302,SeqID2401,SeqID2402,SeqID2403,SeqID2501,SeqID2502,SeqID2503,SeqID2601,SeqID2602,SeqID2603,SeqID2701,
SeqID2702,SeqID2703,SeqID2704,SeqID2801,SeqID2901,SeqID2902,SeqID3001,SeqID3002,SeqID3101,SeqID3201,SeqID3202,SeqID3203,SeqID3204,SeqID3301,SeqID3302,SeqID3401,SeqID3402,SeqID3501,SeqID3502,SeqID3601,SeqID3602,SeqID3603,SeqID3604,SeqID3605,
SeqID3606,SeqID3701,SeqID3702,SeqID3703,SeqID3704,SeqID3801,SeqID3802,SeqID3803,SeqID3804,SeqID3901,SeqID3902,SeqID3903,SeqID3904,SeqID4001,SeqID4002,SeqID4003,SeqID4101,SeqID4102,SeqID4201,SeqID4202,SeqID4301,SeqID4302,SeqID4303,SeqID4304,
SeqID4401,SeqID4501,SeqID4502,SeqID4503,SeqID4504,SeqID4505,SeqID4506,SeqID4507,SeqID4508,SeqID4509,SeqID4510,SeqID4511,SeqID4512,SeqID4513,SeqID4514,SeqID4601,SeqID4602,SeqID4603,SeqID4604,SeqID4701,SeqID4702,SeqID4703,SeqID4704,SeqID4705 FROM ROSE_Hist
WHERE UniqueID = '1919' AND  1 IN ( SeqID0101,SeqID0102,SeqID0103 ,SeqID0104,SeqID0105,SeqID0106,SeqID0107,SeqID0108,SeqID0109,SeqID0110,SeqID0201,SeqID0202,SeqID0203,SeqID0301,SeqID0302,SeqID0303,SeqID0304,SeqID0401,SeqID0402,SeqID0403,SeqID0404,SeqID0501,
SeqID0502,SeqID0601,SeqID0602,SeqID0701,SeqID0702,SeqID0801,SeqID0802,SeqID0901,SeqID0902,SeqID0903,SeqID1001,SeqID1002,SeqID1003,SeqID1004,SeqID1101,SeqID1102,SeqID1201,SeqID1302,SeqID1303,SeqID1304,SeqID1305,
SeqID1401,SeqID1402,SeqID1403,SeqID1404,SeqID1405,SeqID1406,SeqID1407,SeqID1408,SeqID1409,SeqID1410,SeqID1411,SeqID1501,SeqID1502,SeqID1504,SeqID1505,SeqID1601,SeqID1602,SeqID1603,SeqID1604,SeqID1605,SeqID1701,SeqID1702,SeqID1703,SeqID1704,
SeqID1705,SeqID1801,SeqID1802,SeqID1901,SeqID1902,SeqID2001,SeqID2002,SeqID2101,SeqID2102,SeqID2201,SeqID2202,SeqID2203,SeqID2301,SeqID2302,SeqID2401,SeqID2402,SeqID2403,SeqID2501,SeqID2502,SeqID2503,SeqID2601,SeqID2602,SeqID2603,SeqID2701,
SeqID2702,SeqID2703,SeqID2704,SeqID2801,SeqID2901,SeqID2902,SeqID3001,SeqID3002,SeqID3101,SeqID3201,SeqID3202,SeqID3203,SeqID3204,SeqID3301,SeqID3302,SeqID3401,SeqID3402,SeqID3501,SeqID3502,SeqID3601,SeqID3602,SeqID3603,SeqID3604,SeqID3605,
SeqID3606,SeqID3701,SeqID3702,SeqID3703,SeqID3704,SeqID3801,SeqID3802,SeqID3803,SeqID3804,SeqID3901,SeqID3902,SeqID3903,SeqID3904,SeqID4001,SeqID4002,SeqID4003,SeqID4101,SeqID4102,SeqID4201,SeqID4202,SeqID4301,SeqID4302,SeqID4303,SeqID4304,
SeqID4401,SeqID4501,SeqID4502,SeqID4503,SeqID4504,SeqID4505,SeqID4506,SeqID4507,SeqID4508,SeqID4509,SeqID4510,SeqID4511,SeqID4512,SeqID4513,SeqID4514,SeqID4601,SeqID4602,SeqID4603,SeqID4604,SeqID4701,SeqID4702,SeqID4703,SeqID4704,SeqID4705) ORDER BY Room ASC
```

Of course, filtering within the loop is also a possibility, but it's better practice to only request the data you actually need. So if you only need to output those columns, you should only select those columns.

Comment: Hi all. I changed the query to only select the fields starting with "Seq" as per Connum reply. I then used Mawia HL reply foreach ($row_RoomAudit as $key => $val) {
       if (strpos($val, '1') !== FALSE && substr( $val, 0, 3)=='Seq' ){
          print "$key = $val\n";
       }
    } but this does not echo out any result. I know that the first two fields contain "1". Any ideas?

Comment: Then please show us your full code, especially the way from the query to `$row_RoomAudit`
And by the way you do not need to do BOTH, select only the columns and then filter something in the loop.

Comment: Hi Connum, Following the query I have: $RoomAudit = mysql_query($query_RoomAudit, $iMaint) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_RoomAudit = mysql_fetch_assoc($RoomAudit);
    $totalRows_RoomAudit = mysql_num_rows($RoomAudit); Followed by foreach ($row_RoomAudit as $key => $val) {
       if (strpos($val, '1') !== FALSE && substr( $val, 0, 3)=='Seq' ){
          print "$key = $val\n";
       }
    } The reason I select all the "Seq" fields and use them in the filter is to only return the fields that contain "1". Or am I doing this wrong?